# Obtain a Blogger's blog ID from its friendly URL without screen scraping

Tags: php, blogger

I'm using the [Blogger API for PHP](http://code.google.com/apis/blogger/docs/1.0/developers_guide_php.html). I want to obtain the blog ID from just the site's name.

For example, `http://sleeptalkinman.blogspot.com/` has a blog ID of 3117168333067506122. This is possible as the blog ID appears in the source, but screen scraping isn't a good idea!

Is it possible to obtain it through the API instead of scraping it from the HTML?

Answer (score 4):

Today, the newest blogger API is in version 3.0. With that new API, we can get blog ID with resource type `getByUrl`. This is full example using my blog and my API:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/byurl?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ifaniqbal.com&key=AIzaSyDNkR52eSfObZi9BPKrTytbowOAM7Js9uY
```

Just Ctrl+C that example and Ctrl+V to your browser to test that. One of return field of that example is 'id' field, which is the blog ID that we want (in JSON), like this:

```
{
"kind": "blogger#blog",
"id": "7107469463017369923",
"name": "Ifan Iqbal",
"description": "Tips, Download, Resensi, Tutorial, Blog, Blogspot",
"published": "2012-02-28T23:54:48+07:00",
"updated": "2013-07-11T16:24:58+07:00",
"url": "http://www.ifaniqbal.com/",
"selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/7107469463017369923",
"posts": {
 "totalItems": 161,
 "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/7107469463017369923/posts"
},
"pages": {
 "totalItems": 2,
 "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/7107469463017369923/pages"
},
"locale": {
 "language": "in",
 "country": "",
 "variant": ""
}
```

}

Comment: Here's a link to the docs: https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/using#retrieving-a-blog-by-its-url

Comment: The command requires unfortunately an API key to be provided.

Answer (score 3):

(I had posted an original answer, but modified it to use Zend_Gdata instead).

Here is a method of getting the blog ID.

```
<?php

$user = 'username';
$pass = 'password';

// I have to admit, I would normally use the autoloader
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Query');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Feed');

$client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($user, $pass, 'blogger', null,
    Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::DEFAULT_SOURCE, null, null,
    Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::CLIENTLOGIN_URI, 'GOOGLE');
$gdClient = new Zend_Gdata($client);

/**
 * Get the blog ID
 * @param string $feed URL to blog feed or blog name
 *  Example:
 *   - http://googleblog.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default
 */
function getBlogId($gdClient, $feed)
{
    // You could build the /feed/posts/default part yourself and just pass
    // googleblog.blogspot.com:
    // $feed = 'http://' . $feed . '/feeds/posts/default';
    $query = new Zend_Gdata_Query($feed);
    $feed = $gdClient->getFeed($query);
    preg_match('/blog-([0-9]+)/', $feed->id->text, $match);

    if (isset($match[1]))
    {
        return $match[1];
    }

    return false;
}

echo getBlogId($gdClient, 'http://sleeptalkinman.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default');
```

---

**Original answer**

If you're trying to retrieve information, then you should simply be able to replace the www.blogger.com part and ignore the blogID. For example, if you're trying to find all posts from http://dailyvim.blogspot.com/ you would use:

http://dailyvim.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default

Instead of the normal URL, http://www.blogger.com/feeds/[blogID]/posts/default

This method may also work for publishing to the blog, so long as the authenticated user has write access to it. I have not been able to test this, though.

**Getting the blog ID**

You can get the blog ID from the feed above using the following:

```
$content = file_get_contents('http://sleeptalkinman.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default');
preg_match('/<id>.*blog-([0-9]+)</id>/U', $content, $match);
print $match[1]; // Prints the blog ID
```

**Getting post IDs for latest posts**

You can also get the latest posts from the above feed (this time I'll use SimpleXML instead):

```
$feed = simplexml_load_file('http://sleeptalkinman.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default');
foreach ($feed->entry as $entry) 
{
    // I'm getting both the blog ID and post ID
    preg_match('/blog-([0-9]+).*post-([0-9]+)/', $entry->id, $match);
    print $match[2];

    // Now you can use the following URL with the blogger API
    $comment_feed_url = 'http://www.blogger.com/feeds/' . $match[1] . '/' . $match[2] . '/comments/default';
}
```

Comment: Thanks but what Im asking is a step to a bigger question where I wish to retreive the comment feed for a specific post. Again, example!
http://www.blogger.com/feeds/3117168333067506122/5498538184176328230/comments/default

So really Id like to retreive the blog ID fro the first parameter then post ID for the second.

Comment: Well, you can easily get the blog ID from the feed. I've edited my original answer with code to do that.

Comment: Yeah I can do that but I want to avoid loading the page, I was just looking for Blogger API functionallity to return it.

Comment: I've posted a method of getting the blog ID using Zend_Gdata. Please note that Zend_Gdata *is* making an HTTP call to the feed regardless. This method will better integrate with the API though.

Comment: I liked the original answer going via the feed url. No idea what thies Zend_Gdata is but it looks much more complex and requires some Login/auth? I would split this answer in two because you have here two different solutions. I've upvoted for the original one only ;-)

Answer (score -1):

```
$blog = "sleeptalkinman.blogger.com";

$username = split('\.', $blog)[0];
```

should give you what you're after, as long as you have the URL like above.

Answer (score -1):

Seems you can use the blog's url to get the comments as well, try;

http://someusername.blogspot.com/feeds/comments/default

And you can get all the comments for a given post in the similar way, namely /feeds/xxxxxxxx/comments/default, where xxxxxxxx is the post ID.

And you can qualify by date by using the query string ?published-min=2010-03-16T00:00:00&published-max=2010-03-24T23:59:59

As a side note, the Blogger API can return the feed as JSON rather than XML, which I found way easier to deal with than parsing XML by using the query string ?alt=json

Comment: Oh, and the JSON format is described at http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/json.html